# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Failed to package project

Tags: xcode

I've got this problem while trying to archive the project & upload to the app store
while the project runs smoothly on simulator and has no bugs

How this could be solved ?

''' /bin/sh -c /Users/halahelan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-acvmovofiqkicaakwqhfghmprtds/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh
'''

xcode version 13.4.1

Comment: What do the build logs show?

Comment: Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-18 14:58:15.617 xcodebuild[64917:262530] Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem , just check the provisioning profile and re-archive it will be resolved

check provisioning means , re doing it , recreation , adding ,etc ..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).